# Python : Removing duplicates in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

The task i recieved :

Examples of running the sequence_del function :

```
>>> sequence_del("ppyyyyythhhhhooonnnnn") 
'python'
>>> sequence_del("SSSSsssshhhh") 
'Ssh'
>>> sequence_del("Heeyyy   yyouuuu!!!") 
'Hey you!'
```

The code I wrote :

```
def sequence_del(my_str):  # the function deletes duplicated characters.
    l = []
    for ch in my_str:
        if ch not in l:
            l.append(ch)
    print("".join(l))
```

For some reason i can't think of a way to cover the 3rd example in the task . 
Would love some help with it !

Comment: So what if the string is Uhm, `Moon`?

Comment: @9769953 got it, so the solution is `''.join(k for k,_ in itertools.groupby("Heeyyy   yyouuuu!!!"))`

Comment: @9769953 it's already in the answers (of the linked duplicate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
def sequence_del(my_str):  # the function deletes duplicated characters.
    l = []
    last=''
    for ch in my_str:
        if last!=ch:
            l.append(ch)
            last = ch

    print("".join(l))
```

Comment: This one covers it , thanks a lot !
Is there any chance i can contanct you with another questions ?

Comment: @LiranSarel, SO welcomes you with quality questions.